# spawn 4 linux terminal from one script

Tags: linux, terminal

I have 4 shell commands which I want to run in a separate shell each.

Since I am really bothered by opening 4 shells manually every time and type in each command, I was wondering if there is a way to write a script for this.

My commands are:

```
./supercomponent --cid=111 
./vehicle --cid=111 --freq=10 
./cockpit--cid=111 
./irus --cid=111 --freq=10
```

Comment: Try https://www.google.com/webhp?q=bash%20scripting#q=bash+scripting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can nest the commands in braces, which run in its own execution environment with it's own variables and such in the backgrounds i.e. in a new bash program instance.

```
( ./supercomponent --cid=111 ) &
( ./vehicle --cid=111 --freq=10 ) &
( ./cockpit--cid=111 ) &
( ./irus --cid=111 --freq=10 )
```

Comment: my script looks like this   cd /opt/odv/bin

{./supercomponent --cid=111}
{./vehicle --cid=111 --freq=10}
{./cockpit --cid=111}
{./irus --cid=111 --freq=10}

Comment: You must separate the curly braces from your command code with single white spaces

Comment: i did, now it tells me syntax error unexpected end of file

Comment: check if the change returns the program flow to the main script

Comment: What's with the `$` signs? `$()` is interpolation, not a subshell.